# Python Selenium - get href value

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to copy the href value from a website, and the html code looks like this:

```
<p class="sc-eYdvao kvdWiq">
 <a href="https://www.iproperty.com.my/property/setia-eco-park/sale- 
 1653165/">Shah Alam Setia Eco Park, Setia Eco Park
 </a>
</p>
```

I've tried `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".sc-eYdvao.kvdWiq").get_attribute("href")` but it returned `'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'`. Using `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".sc-eYdvao.kvdWiq").get_attribute("href")` returned `None`. But i cant use xpath because the website has like 20+ href which i need to copy all. Using xpath would only copy one.

If it helps, all the 20+ href are categorised under the same class which is `sc-eYdvao kvdWiq`.

Ultimately i would want to copy all the 20+ href and export them out to a csv file.

Appreciate any help possible.

Comment: Update the question with a bit more of the _outerHTML_

Comment: Can you also include the url?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You want driver.find_elements if more than one element. This will return a list. For the css selector you want to ensure you are selecting for those classes that have a child href

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".sc-eYdvao.kvdWiq [href]")
links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elems]
```

You might also need a wait condition for presence of all elements located by css selector.

```
elems = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".sc-eYdvao.kvdWiq [href]")))
```

Comment: There's a typo in the wait condition: it should be WebDriverWait(driver,10).until ... [with a closing bracket between '10' and '.until').

Comment: Thank you worked beautifully also for my case although I am using  find_elements_by_class_name

Answer (score 26):

As per the given HTML:

```
<p class="sc-eYdvao kvdWiq">
    <a href="https://www.iproperty.com.my/property/setia-eco-park/sale-1653165/">Shah Alam Setia Eco Park, Setia Eco Park</a>
</p>
```

As the `href` attribute is within the `<a>` tag ideally you need to move deeper till the `<a>` node. So to extract the value of the `href` *attribute* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("p.sc-eYdvao.kvdWiq > a").get_attribute('href'))
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='sc-eYdvao kvdWiq']/a").get_attribute('href'))
  ```

---

If you want to extract all the values of the `href` *attribute* you need to use `find_elements*` instead:

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("p.sc-eYdvao.kvdWiq > a")])
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//p[@class='sc-eYdvao kvdWiq']/a")])
  ```

---

### Dynamic elements

However, if you observe the **values** of *class* attributes i.e. `sc-eYdvao` and `kvdWiq` ideally those are **dynamic** values. So to extract the `href` attribute you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies*:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p.sc-eYdvao.kvdWiq > a"))).get_attribute('href'))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[@class='sc-eYdvao kvdWiq']/a"))).get_attribute('href'))
  ```

---

If you want to extract all the values of the `href` *attribute* you can use `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` instead:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p.sc-eYdvao.kvdWiq > a")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//p[@class='sc-eYdvao kvdWiq']/a")))])
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait     
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By     
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 3):

Get the whole element you want with `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, 'path')`.
To extract the href link use `get_attribute('href')`.
Which gives,

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, 'path').get_attribute('href')
```

Answer (score 0):

The XPATH

```
//p[@class='sc-eYdvao kvdWiq']/a
```

return the elements you are looking for.

Writing the data to CSV file is not related to the scraping challenge. Just try to look at examples and you will be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To crawl any hyperlink or Href, proxycrwal API is ideal as it uses pre-built functions for fetching desired information. Just pip install the API and follow the code to get the required output. The second approach to fetch Href links using python selenium is to run the following code.

> Source Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

list = ['https://www.heliosholland.com/Ampullendoos-voor-63-ampullen','https://www.heliosholland.com/lege-testdozen’]
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,29)

for i in list: 
  driver.get(i)
  image = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/img'))).get_attribute('src')
  print(image)
```

To scrape the link, use .get_attribute(‘src’).

Answer (score -3):

try something like:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//p[contains(@class, 'sc-eYdvao') and contains(@class='kvdWiq')]/a")
for elem in elems:
   print elem.get_attribute['href']
```