# Extracting text from a website using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

trying to find a way to extract the book's summary from the good reads page. Have tried Beautiful soup / Selenium, unfortunately to no avail.

link:https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/67896.Tao_Te_Ching?from_search=true&from_srp=true&qid=D19iQu7KWI&rank=1

code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
link='https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/67896.Tao_Te_Ching?from_search=true&from_srp=true&qid=D19iQu7KWI&rank=1'
driver.get(link)
Description=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'TextContainer')]")
#first TextContainer contains the sumary of the book
book_page = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(book_page.text, "html.parser")
print(soup)
Container = soup.find('class', class_='leftContainer')
print(Container)
```

Error:

> container is empty +
>
> NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(text(),'TextContainer')]"}
> (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)

Comment: Try to add an explicit wait for the element.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the description like so

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
...
driver.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/67896.Tao_Te_Ching?from_search=true&from_srp=true&qid=D19iQu7KWI&rank=1")
description = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#description span[style="display:none"]'))
)
print(description.get_attribute('textContent'))
```

I have utilised a [CSS Selector](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors)  to get the specific hidden `span` that contains the full description. I have also used an [explicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to give the element time to load.