# Access attribute inside of tag

Tags: python, selenium

My goal is to access a list of links (located in `"event?id=85042"`).

```html
<tr class="gvrow"> == $0
  <td>...</td>
  <td>
    <a href="event?id=85042"
                                text
                              </a>
  </td>

  ...
```

This repeats too, so I want to get a list of the links located in event?id=...
I've tried this approach from this question [Python Selenium - get href value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54862426/python-selenium-get-href-value) but it is returning a list full of None

```py
primary_links = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('gvrow')
links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in primary_links]
print(links)
```

Output:

```py
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Desired Output:

```py
['https://www.iccf.com/event?id=85042', 'https://www.iccf.com/event?id=79897', 'https://www.iccf.com/event?id=66745', ...]
```

How would I do it then?

Here is a better representation of the html
[image]

Comment: Well, the anchors do not have the class `gvrow`, do they? The table rows have the class, but you need to search for anchors therewithin.

Comment: Can you please share the complete HTML? Otherwise it is quite impossible to give proper feedback.

Comment: The tag seems to be incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following line of code you will get a list containing the `<td>` element and any other element having `class=gvrow`:

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('gvrow')
```

Obviously, the `<td>` element(s) you get back do not have the `href` attribute.

Instead of your approach, you could use another method the get the link:

```
a_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@class='gvrow']/td/a")
links = [a_element.get_attribute('href') for a_element in a_elements]
```