# Selenium + Python: Print text of an element located by CssSelector

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am new to Selenium and Python.
I would like to navigate through a website, find an element and print it (or store it in a csv file).

Python version: 3.10; Selenium Webdriver: Firefox; IDE: PyCharm 2021.3.2 (CE);
OS: Fedora 35 VM

So far I am able to navigate to the appropriate page where a table is generated. When I locate the element by CSS Selector and attempt to print it, the output does not print the text "$10.50" that I see on the screen. In fact, it does not print anything.

HTML code of the element I am trying to print:

```
<input id="b8-b36-Input_RemainAmtYr1" class="form-control OSFillParent" data-input="" disabled="" type="text" style="margin-top: 5px;" value="$10.50">
event
```

My relevant code:

```
RemainDue = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#b8-b36-Input_RemainAmtYr1')
print ('Remaining Due:', RemainDue.text)
```

I expect the output to be "$10.50", which is what I see on the screen and in the HTML. Instead I get the following:

> Remaining Due:

There is nothing printed after "Remaining Due:"
I thought the problem was that the "$10.50" was possibly being generated by some sort of javascript but I can see the text "$10.50" that I want to print in the HTML code above.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like HTML id will change on every page load, can you share the URL or more HTML code for better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the value of the *value* attribute i.e. ***$10.50*** you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.form-control.OSFillParent[id$='Input_RemainAmtYr1']").get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='form-control OSFillParent' and contains(@id, 'Input_RemainAmtYr1')]").get_attribute("value"))
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control.OSFillParent[id$='Input_RemainAmtYr1']"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='form-control OSFillParent' and contains(@id, 'Input_RemainAmtYr1')]"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [Python Selenium - get href value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62821486/7429447)

Comment: The "Using CSS_SELECTOR:" method worked! Thank you so much. Pycharm prompted me to make the following sight change: print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control.OSFillParent[id$='Input_RemainAmtYr1']").get_attribute("value"))
Not sure if it has to do with the version of Selenium I am using. I have been trying to figure this out how to print this out for over a week before I posted the question. Is there anywhere I can read up on how to print the value of value attributes?

Comment: @Auditor Checkout the updated answer and let me know if you have any further queries.

Comment: The WebDriverWait code you provided does work if I replace 'visibility_of_element_located' with 'presence_of_element_located'. It does locate the element & I am able to extract the text attribute of that element. But I am concerned because apparently best use dictates that I should use 'visibility_of_element_located' if I want to extract any attribute of any element & I do need to extract the text attribute. Why would WebDriverWait work for me with 'presence_of_element_located'  and not work with 'visibility_of_element_located'? The code is otherwise identical.

Comment: I think I understand now. The element I am trying to extract the text attribute from is not visible on the page unless another tab is clicked. I didn't bother adding the Selenium code to click that tab first because the locate code was able to extract the text attribute prior to adding WebDriverWait to it. When I did add WebDriverWait, I was using 'visibility_of_element_located' even though that element was not visible. When I changed it to 'presence_of_element_located' I was able to extract the text attribute from it.

Comment: Do you think it is okay to leave the code as 'presence_of_element_located' even though I am extracting text from it or should I change the code to click the tab first and then use 'visibility_of_element_located'?

Comment: Ideally using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) it is desireable to probe the [_visibility_of_element_located()_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) of an element. However, in real time scenarios at times we do have to compromise on the best practices and such cases it's okay to use [_presence_of_element_located()_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447).