# How to extract text from aria-label attribute?

Tags: html, css, selenium, web-scraping, getattribute

So basically I am trying to work on webscraping. I need to scrap the work life balance rating from indeed website. But the challenge that I am facing is that I do not know how to extract the text from the aria-label, so I can get the output 4.0 out of 5 stars.

```
<div role="img" aria-label="4.0 out of 5 stars."><div class="css-eub7j6 eu4oa1w0"><div data-testid="filledStar" style="width:42.68px" class="css-i84nrz eu4oa1w0"></div></div></div>
```

Comment: You wrote me you having an error. What is the error? Can you share a link to the page you working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify the element and use the get attribute `aria-label` to get the value.

If you are using python. code will be

```
print(diver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@role='img']").get_attribute("aria-label"))
```

---

Update:

```
print(diver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@role='img' and @aria-label]").get_attribute("aria-label"))
```

Or

```
print(diver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@role='img' and @aria-label][.//div[@data-testid='filledStar']]").get_attribute("aria-label"))
```

Comment: giving me errors. Yes I am using python. @KunduK

Comment: @AnnieDhawan, Sorry typo. Can you try now?

Comment: It is not giving me an error now but it is printing None, not giving me 4 out of 5 stars

Comment: @AnnieDhawan, try updated one. Have provided wait to page load properly.

Comment: I got the result using the updated one but I have one doubt can I text you here?

Comment: @AnnieDhawan, Yes you can. I'll try to resolve your query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251205/discussion-between-annie-dhawan-and-kunduk).

Answer (score 0):

In case you can locate that element attribute value can be retrieven with selenium with `get_attribute()` method.
Let's say you are using `By.CSS_SELECTOR` and the locator is `css_selector`.
Python syntax is:

```py
aria_label_value = driver.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, css_selector).get_attribute("aria-label")
```

Same can be done with other programming languages similarly with slight syntax changes

Answer (score 0):

To retrive the value of the *`aria-label`* attribute i.e. *"4.0 out of 5 stars."* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *`role="img"`*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[role='img'][aria-label]"))).get_attribute("aria-label"))
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *`data-testid="filledStar"`*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-testid='filledStar']//ancestor::div[@role='img' and @aria-label]"))).get_attribute("aria-label"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [Python Selenium - get href value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62821486/7429447)