# How to locate a specific image to get the src value with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, getattribute

I am trying to get the src of an image, however, it does not find the element of it does not filter to the image I need.

I have tried a couple of different xpaths and css selector including:

```
imgsrc = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[class="pv-top-card-profile-picture__image pv-top-card-profile-picture__image--show ember-view"]')

#imgsrc = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//img[@class='pv-top-card-profile-picture pv-top-card-profile-picture']")
```

That does not find the element.

```
imgsrc = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "[//img[contains(@src, 'profile-displayphoto')]")
```

Is too broad and finds the incorrect image.

The html is as follows:

```
<div class="pv-top-card__non-self-photo-wrapper ml0">
  
  <button class="pv-top-card-profile-picture pv-top-card-profile-picture__container display-block
      pv-top-card__photo presence-entity__image EntityPhoto-circle-9
      " type="button">
      
      
    <img width="200" title="" src="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E03AQEW8FzkdjFD-w/profile-displayphoto-shrink_400_400/0/1516275678440?e=1683158400&amp;v=beta&amp;t=vmGZHtwkrttxt85prjTTySrnybP7L6lX858TpFgtWaQ" height="200" alt="" id="ember818" class="pv-top-card-profile-picture__image pv-top-card-profile-picture__image--show ember-view">

<!---->
<!---->
    

  </button>

  
<div class="presence-entity__indicator presence-entity__indicator--size-9 presence-indicator
    hidden
    presence-indicator--size-9">
  <span class="visually-hidden">
      Status is offline
      </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the value of the *`src`* attribute you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.pv-top-card-profile-picture > img.pv-top-card-profile-picture__image.pv-top-card-profile-picture__image--show.ember-view").get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'pv-top-card-profile-picture')]/img[@class='pv-top-card-profile-picture__image pv-top-card-profile-picture__image--show ember-view']"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  ```

---

The desired element is a [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/) enabled element, so ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.name[title='Download']"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='name' and @title='Download']"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [Python Selenium - get href value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62821486/7429447)