# Python + selenium+css selector

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

this is the HTML code:

```
 </template>
                            </el-table-column>
                            <el-table-column prop="announcementTitle" label="公告标题">
                                <template slot-scope="scope">
                                <span class="ahover">
                                    <a v-html="scope.row.announcementTitle" target="_blank" :href="linkLastPage(scope.row)"></a>
                                    <span v-show="checkDocType(scope.row.adjunctType)" class="icon-f"><i class="iconfont" :class="[checkDocType(scope.row.adjunctType)]"></i></span>
                                </span>
                                </template>
```

If I want to get the content of annoncementTitle with Python + selenium and css_selector, how should I write the code?

Comment: _content of annoncementTitle_: Do you want to extract the text _`announcementTitle`_ or _`公告标题`_ ?

Comment: 公告标题 is the Chinese translation of announcementTitle

Comment: which text do you want to extract?

Answer (score 0):

Identify the element using following `css_selector` and then use `get_attribute("attribute_name")` to get the atrribute value.

```
print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR , 'el-table-column[prop="announcementTitle"]').get_attribute("label"))
```

you might need some wait to avoid the synchronization issue.

Answer (score 0):

To print the value of the *`<label>`* attribute i.e. ***公告标题*** you need to use [`get_attribute()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53759033/7429447) method and you can use the following [*css_selector*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48578370/7429447) based [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR , 'el-table-column[prop=announcementTitle]').get_attribute("label"))
```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "el-table-column[prop='announcementTitle']"))).get_attribute("label"))
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [Python Selenium - get href value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62821486/7429447)